# Unused import rollup warning without indication of where

Tags: rollupjs

We're seeing warnings like this in our rollup build:

```
{
  code: 'UNUSED_EXTERNAL_IMPORT',
  message: "'tmpdir' is imported from external module 'os' but never used",
  names: [ 'tmpdir' ],
  source: 'os',
  toString: [Function]
}
```

For some reason the source/location of where this warning is not provided, so fixing it becomes a challenge. It may be an issue with third-party code for example, in which case we cannot fix it ourselves.

This warning comes from using the rollup api:

```
rollup({
  onwarn(warning, warn) {
    console.log(warning)
    warn(warning) // produces a message with less information shown than the raw console.log
  },
```